# Compare images with MarvinFramework

Tags: java, image-processing, marvinproject

I am trying to determine differences between two images during an integration test. After doing some research on the web, I stumbled over [the MarvinProject](http://marvinproject.sourceforge.net) and tried to create a UnitTest with it, see below.

As far as I understood the plugin `DifferentRegions`, it will fill the passed `ImageMask differenceMask` with the regions that contain the differences. The two images I pass for the test do differ, so it should print out something.

Unfortunately it does not.

I have written other tests that compare those two images byte-wise and those succeed. For those who want to try the problem, I have created [a repository on GitHub](https://github.com/chriseverty/ImageCompare) and here is [the ImageCompareTest](https://github.com/chriseverty/ImageCompare/blob/master/src/test/java/org/cheffe/imagecompare/ImageCompareTest.java).

```java
@Test
public void tryMarvinProject() {
    // init images
    String root = "src/test/resources/";
    MarvinImage assertedImg = MarvinImageIO.loadImage(root + "image1.bmp");
    MarvinImage actualImg = MarvinImageIO.loadImage(root + "image2.bmp");

    // init diff-regions plugin
    DifferentRegions regions = new DifferentRegions();
    regions.load();
    regions.setAttribute("comparisonImage", assertedImg);

    int width = assertedImg.getWidth();
    int height = assertedImg.getHeight();
    int type = assertedImg.getType();

    // process the images and retrieve differences from the ImageMask
    MarvinImageMask differenceMask = new MarvinImageMask();
    regions.process(
            actualImg,
            new MarvinImage(new BufferedImage(width, height, type)),
            new MarvinAttributes(),
            differenceMask,
            false);

    // should contain the differences, but does not
    System.out.println(differenceMask.getMaskArray());
    assertNotNull(differenceMask.getMaskArray());
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The plug-in DifferentRegions was developed for real-time video processing. The idea is to find the regions in the scene which are changing in a sequence of video frames, as shown in this [Example](http://marvinproject.sourceforge.net/en/examples/motionRegions.html)

For image-to-image comparison, you should try [DifferenceColor](http://marvinproject.sourceforge.net/en/plugins/differenceColor.html) plug-in. Basically, it compare the two images analysing the color intensity of pixels in the same position. If the difference of two given pixels is higher than the attribute **colorRange**, the two pixels are considered distinct in color. The plug-in renders the different pixels in a different color to show them in the output image. If you pass an **MarvinAttributes** object in the **process(...)** method, you can get the number of different pixels, stored in the key **total**.

**Example:**

```
    MarvinAttributes attrOut = new MarvinAttributes();
    MarvinImagePlugin diff = MarvinPluginLoader.loadImagePlugin("org.marvinproject.image.difference.differenceColor");
    diff.process(imageA, imageB, attrOut);
    System.out.println("Distinct pixels:"+attrOut.get("total"));
```

**PS:** In order to use **MarvinPluginLoader** you must configure the development environment following the instructions presented [here](http://marvinproject.sourceforge.net/en/tutorials/02_firstApplication/firstApplication.html).

---

However, since you are trying to use image comparison for Unit Testing, you should take a look at **MarvinTestCase** class. It extends [JUnit](http://junit.org/) TestCase and provide methods to compare MarvinImage objects.

**Input:**

[image]

The source code below implements two test cases, one comparing imageA to imageB, and the other comparing imageA to imageC.

```
import marvin.image.MarvinImage;
import marvin.io.MarvinImageIO;
import marvin.test.MarvinTestCase;

public class UnitTesting extends MarvinTestCase {

    private MarvinImage imageA, imageB, imageC;

    public UnitTesting(){
        imageA = MarvinImageIO.loadImage("./res/penguin.jpg");
        imageB = MarvinImageIO.loadImage("./res/penguin.jpg");
        imageC = MarvinImageIO.loadImage("./res/penguin_dark.jpg");
    }

    public void testSameImage(){
        assertEquals(imageA, imageB);
    }

    public void testDistinctImages(){
        assertEquals(imageA, imageC);
    }
}
```

Using Eclipse or another IDE, run the class above as a JUnit Test. Below the output in the JUnit tab on Eclipse.

[image]